# Running into NameError: name 'app' is not defined when trying to upload image into file

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

My problem occurs mainly when I try and upload a picture in a separate html form. Before I added the app.config I would successfully get POST and GET requests. On visual code it tells me that app is not defined but I'm not sure how to define it in my image.py file.

This is my image.py file app.config

```
from unicodedata import category
    from flask import Flask, Blueprint, render_template, request, flash, jsonify, url_for, redirect
    import urllib.request
    from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
    from flask_login import  login_required , current_user
    from .models import Note
    from .import db
    import json
    import os
    
    
    
    
    image = Blueprint('image', __name__)
    
    
    @image.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
    @login_required
    def Upload():
    
        if request.method == "POST":
            if request.files:
                image = request.files["image"]
    
                image.save(os.path.join(app.config['IMAGE_UPLOADS'], image.filename))
    
                print("image saved")
                return redirect(request.url)
            
        return render_template("image.html", user=current_user)
```

My **init**.py file with my app configurations.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
from flask_login import LoginManager


db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

  
    #Secret key into app
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '****'
    app.config['IMAGE_UPLOADS'] = r"C:\Users\qw\Desktop\StCh\website\static\Images"
   
   
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
```

and finally my main.py file to run the app.

```
from website import create_app


app = create_app()

 
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app.run(debug=True)
```

the error keeps on occurring even after I try and import from website or

Comment: What do you think your `create_app()` returns and assigns to `app` in `main.py`?

Comment: Everything within that function, I do have more to that function but I didn't think it was relevant

Comment: Two things: Your `create_app` function does not *return* a value.  It should have `return app` at the end.  But the actual reason for the `NameError` is in `image.py` you use `app.config['IMAGE_UPLOADS']` but `app` is not defined in that module.  For this you can use [flask.current_app](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/appcontext/#purpose-of-the-context)

Comment: @ProofDoubloon no, functions only return what you tell them to. Yours doesn't return anything.

Comment: i do have return app at the end

Comment: Oh, I don't know how could I've missed that. Might be because you *didn't include that in your code.*

Comment: yes i apologise

Comment: Btw it says 'Flask' object is not subscriptable, is there no way of just importing app from the __init__ file

Answer (score -1):

I resolved it by just adding

```
app = Flask(__name__)
```

into my image.py file. Feel stupid